# Generate GUID in XSLT

Tags: c#, xslt, guid, umbraco

I need to generate a GUID with XSLT and if needed C#, does anyone know how to best do this?

It is to generate unique IDs for HTML items.

Comment: There is a short XPath expression for this, See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64792196/36305

Answer (score 3):

The XSLT [`generate-id` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) returns a string that uniquely identifies a node in the document. Note these warnings from the spec:

> An implementation is under no
>   obligation to generate the same
>   identifiers each time a document is
>   transformed. There is no guarantee
>   that a generated unique identifier
>   will be distinct from any unique IDs
>   specified in the source document.

However, if all you need is to uniquely identify each element in your output, then `generate-id` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but the xslt file will be called multiple times on the one page generating one item per time so I don;t think the generate-id would work. ANy other ideas?

Comment: @Burt - See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509662/how-to-generate-unique-string/4511181#4511181

Answer (score 1):

C# provides a handy Guid.NewGuid() static method.  I'd expect any XSLT implementation would heavily leverage some system-specific component since Guids are often generated in part based on hardware/MAC address/etc. on the underlying machine.

Comment: I know about the Guid.NewGuid but how would I call that from XSLT?

Comment: One way is via a XSL extension method like here: http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/Calling-C-function-in-XSL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just using an extension method and wrapping Guid.NewGuid() in a static method, then calling this from my XSLT, it was easy enough once I figured out how extension methods work.

Answer (score 0):

With C#, it can be achieved easily with [Script Blocks Using msxsl:script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts">
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
  <![CDATA[
  public string getguid(){
     return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  }
  ]]>
  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <Guid><xsl:value-of select="user:getguid()"/></Guid>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```