# XSLT: Hashing URI string

Tags: xml, xslt, hash, unique

I need to generate unique IDs for elements across multiple XML files using XSLT.  Each of the elements in question is already provided an ID that is gaurenteed to be unique within its own file, but can (and will) overlap with the IDs of nodes in other files.

My solution has been to concat the file path to the beginning of the existing ID, but this poses 2 problems:

1. Publishing the filepath is a less than ideal solution, and may pose a legal/security risk.
2. It makes for some *very* long, and verbose IDs filled with illegal characters (slashes, anyone?).  The output is an HTML page, and many of the computers accessing it are old, and run ancient picky browsers.

This is the code I'm running with, currently:

```
<xsl:template match="box">
    <div class="box">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$file_path" /><xsl:value-of select="./@id" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        ... blah blah content blah ...
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

`$file_path` is passed in as a param automatically by the system.

So, yes, while this (technically) works, it is far from up to snuff.  What I'd like to do is hash the variable `$file_path` before jamming together with the other ID.  It doesn't have to be super secure, just obfuscated enough so that it doesn't resemble a path, is totally alpha-numeric, and is, preferably, shorter (bonus points if all  hashes are the same length).

Finally (and this is the clincher) **it almost certainly has to work in XSLT 1.0**.  It may be possible to persuade the powers that be to upgrade, but for all intents and purposes I need to know if this can be done without XSLT 2.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509662/how-to-generate-unique-string

Comment: @MarkVeenstra Close, but if I'm understanding that answer correctly, that just puts an iterator before the ID.  If I have two documents each with an elements with the same ID, and they both happen to be the *nth* element with an ID (quite likely given the scheme the system I'm working with uses for assigning IDs) then there will be overlap.

Comment: Pass in some parameter, like a GUID and use that

Comment: @KevinBrown Hmmm, interesting.  I COULD hash the URI outside of the XSLT, or use the file system's built in ID system (as I think you're suggesting).  That could totally work!  Submit it as an answer and I'll pick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an xsl:param, pass into the transform some unique key like a GUID. It would give you unique id's.

Comment: This works, and as a bonus I can hash outside of the XSLT before passing it in (so I could even use the path!)  Thanks!